implementation of trait is not general enough
Let's say I have access to the following functions:
trait T<'a> {}
impl<'a> T<'a> for &'a str {} 
fn takes_fn(f: impl Fn(&str)) {}

fn take_both<'a, X:T<'a>>(a: &'a str, f: impl Fn(X) -> String) {}

// works
fn specific() {
   takes_fn(|s| take_both(s, str::to_lowercase))
}

This compiles fine. But I'm trying to create a generic version of specific that accepts any function that takes a type that implements T<'a>, so that I can call generic(str::to_lowercase) instead of specific.
I initially tried
// broken
fn generic_2<X>(f: fn(X) -> String)
where for<'a> X: T<'a> {
    takes_fn(move |s| take_both(s, f))
}

but it doesn't work, because T<'a> is only implemented for &'a str, not for any &str.
I also tried
// broken
fn generic_1<'a, X:T<'a>>(f: fn(X) -> String) {
    takes_fn(move |s| take_both(s, f))
}

but it doesn't work because of the constraints on take_fn.
Playyground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cf8a9ebe41c29464712b7bbec9c00b71

I don't believe this is possible.

This can be done by using higher kinded types. It can even be done a little bit nicer by using some tricks in the lending iterator crate. But unless you really need this function, I would not recommend using higher kinded types, as they are annoying to work with.

Oh, great ! Thank you both for the solution and the advice !
